# Loading a plugin into an embedded version of Neo4j database

Tags: java, neo4j, graphaware, neo4j-apoc

In a standalone version of Neo4j database server, there's this `plugin` folder in which I can copy [APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) library and then use its awesome functions in my queries. Right now, I'm trying to do the same in a test Java project which instantiates an embedded version of Neo4j, using the [Graphaware](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework) framework.

My question is, how can I feed the APOC library to the embedded version of the Neo4j when it is setup like this:

```
class ModuleTest
{
    GraphDatabaseService database;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        String confFile = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("neo4j-module.conf").getPath();
        database = new TestGraphDatabaseFactory()
                .newImpermanentDatabaseBuilder()
                .loadPropertiesFromFile(confFile)
                .newGraphDatabase();
    }
}
```

?

Comment: were you successful on this?

Comment: @WantIt Yes I did, using the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to register the procedure classes that you want to use during your test.

An example is in the APOC TestUtil :

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.0/src/test/java/apoc/util/TestUtil.java#L89